# TKinter child objects: TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm somewhat experienced with python and pretty new to tkinter. I'm trying to arrange four frames in a 2x2 grid and as of know I'm failing miserably. I tried to create a MWE and even that failed as in it does neither work nor recreate my actual problem but produces one of it's own. But first things first, the MWE Code is as following:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


class DummyParent(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        super().__init__(master)
        master.title('Test')
        self.children = []
        for i in range(4):
            self.children.append(DummyChild(self))
            self.children[i].grid(row=i//2, column=i%2)


class DummyChild(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.state(ttk.Label(text='Test'))


root = tk.Tk()

dP = DummyParent(master=root)
dP.mainloop()
```

Which results in the following stack trace:

```
  File "E:/TI/internetofthings/python/tkinter_test.py", line 23, in <module>
    dP = DummyParent(master=root)
  File "E:/TI/internetofthings/python/tkinter_test.py", line 11, in __init__
    self.children.append(DummyChild(self))
  File "E:/TI/internetofthings/python/tkinter_test.py", line 17, in __init__
    super().__init__(master)
  File "C:\Users\Scipio\anaconda3\lib\tkinter\ttk.py", line 742, in __init__
    Widget.__init__(self, master, "ttk::frame", kw)
  File "C:\Users\Scipio\anaconda3\lib\tkinter\ttk.py", line 559, in __init__
    tkinter.Widget.__init__(self, master, widgetname, kw=kw)
  File "C:\Users\Scipio\anaconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2292, in __init__
    BaseWidget._setup(self, master, cnf)
  File "C:\Users\Scipio\anaconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2285, in _setup
    self.master.children[self._name] = self
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

The value of `self._name` at the time of the error is `!dummyparent`. What really confuses me is that my original code is working perfectly fine to that point and beyond even though it's pretty much the same with some actual functionality added. At the same line of library code the value of `self._name` is `!firefightermonitor`, the equivalent classes name(in lower case with leading exclamation mark, just as for the MWE). So, any idea what I'm missing here? Or am I simply using tkinter wrong?

Comment: Why are you passing the label to `self.state`? What are you trying to accomplish by doing that?

Comment: I was trying to get some content into the frame so that it's not empty. I'm copied that from a tutorial or stackoverflow answer on images but would be happy to learn the 'proper' way. That said, omitting the whole line does not change the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a lot of small problems in your code.

The biggest problem, unfortunately, is that you're defining `self.children` which clashes with an internal (and, sadly, undocumented) attribute of the same name. You need to rename your attribute to something else. I don't know why you're keeping the children in an array. Tkinter does that for you so I don't think the `self.children` list is necessary at all.

The next problem is that you should not be calling `self.state` the way you are. That's simply not how you use `self.state`.

The label in `DummyChild` needs to be a child of the `self`. You are neglecting to pass in the parent/master so it's defaulting to being a child of root.

You need to call `pack`, `place` or `grid` on the label so that it appears in the child. You also need to call one of those methods on `dP` as well, so that it appears in the root.

Putting it all together, this creates a 2x2 grid with your labels visible:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


class DummyParent(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        super().__init__(master)
        master.title('Test')
        for row in range(0,2):
            for column in range(0,2):
                child = DummyChild(self)
                child.grid(row=row, column=column, sticky="nsew")


class DummyChild(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.label = ttk.Label(self, text='Test')
        self.label.pack()

root = tk.Tk()

dP = DummyParent(master=root)
dP.pack()
dP.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you very muched for that detailed answer which solved both the problem in the MWE and the different problem in the original code. Just one thing: How do I adress a specific child element somewhere else in the code?